# Updating Redundant data/denormalized data in NoSQL(Aerospike)

Tags: nosql, updates, aerospike

My question is that I am having a problem where I need to update the data which is been denormalized due to being in NoSQL because a single update in one data needs to be updated in all other redundant data.

For eg: Consider an e-commerce database where there is one table "Products" which contains all the details about a product , let's say name,imageName, LogoImage
Now in this case the LogoImage of various "Products" table entry can be same, and now I need to update the LogoImage, so I need to update in all the fields which contains the given LogoImage. which seems like a very poor solution

So is there any better way to do that?

P.S.: If we seperate logo and Products into 2 different table  , so when I need to get 1000 products at a time , I need to get the related logos by implementing a client level join type thing, which is also not a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're suggesting using the database as your CDN and storing the binary image in it? That's not a great approach, in my opinion. You should be storing that image in an actual CDN like Amazon Cloudfront, or a simple one like Amazon S3, or your own webserver as a file. Whichever, the point is that you should be referring to it by URI. In Aerospike you would store the metadata about that image, not the image itself.

Next, you can have two sets - `prod` for products and `prodimg` for product images. The various products store a list of IDs referring to the product image set. The product image set has metadata about each image as a separate record { uri, name, title, width, length, ... } . If anything changes about this image, you just update the one record with the metadata for that image in `prodimg`. No need to change anything about the products.

And you don't really need JOIN functionality in this case. Your application can get the `prod` record first, and use the bin (`images`) that has all the IDs of the images for the product (each referring to a key of a record in `prodimg`). You can then issue either a few get operations (reads) or a single [batch-read](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/batch.html) for all of them if there are many. The latencies for Aerospike are such that this will return faster and scale better than an equivalent JOIN in an RDBMS. A batch-read is a multi-node, multi-core, multi-threaded operation. A cluster of 3 multi-core nodes has plenty of parallel computing power.

Again, if you "need 1000 products at a time" use batch-read. In the Java client that's an [`AerospikeClient.get()`](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/AerospikeClient.html#get(com.aerospike.client.policy.BatchPolicy,%20com.aerospike.client.Key[])) with a list of [`Key`](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/Key.html) objects. In the Python client that's an [`aerospike.Client.get_many`](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/client.html#aerospike.Client.get_many). Every Aerospike client has batch-read functionality.

Comment: .Hello Ronen, 
Thankyou for the help , I was storing the URI only for the image in the products table.
Also the way you are telling to use won't it be a slow solution? 
Also is it okay to use Aerospike for the data which might get updated time to time? Because most the data will be in denormalized form which will lead to redundancy and changing the bin values which contains same data due to denormalization will require many updates /operates in Aerospike. Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Aerospike is between 10-100x faster than your RDBMS. You getting multiple records at once will still be faster. Your RDBMS backed application is already denormalized into mostly single table PK access or maybe a join to a sub-table (Users and Vehicles). Nobody has a web application using 3rd normal form, right? Aerospike doesn't have to do most joins because of the complex data types list and map. Actually I suggested to use IDs in a list, which is similar to a foreign key, so you adjust only one location (`prodimg`). Aerospike is a real distributed database, not a cache.

Comment: Thankyou Ronen for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Vote the answer up if it solves your issue.

Comment: It clears up a lot of confusion. But right now I am not having enough reputation to vote the answers as I am new to Stackoverflow.